# Hibernate with Fuse - Failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: com.connecture.exemplar.entity -

Tags: web-services, hibernate, fuseesb, jbossfuse

My problem is peciluar, Please assist me in any way if you can !!

I have around more than 1300 of hibernate entity files, which are by default loaded with lazy intilization. I deployed them with tomcat and able to run web services using them with cxf, the application runs successfuly. With the same enity files, I made a budle in Fuse, the services are been deployed , while running the application , it gives an error saying "Failed to lazily initialize a collection of role" with entity names.

Now for this I came with one solution that at place of 
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "prProductLines") , I changed the FetechType with Lazy to EAGER. The problem get resolved.

But now, while changing at all places the fetch type to EAGER, this modification raised me another problem, where the query runs very slow taking too much long time, finally it reports error in SQl server 2008 with "There is insufficient system memory in resource pool 'internal' to run this query." and in console "org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not load an entity"

Now please suggest me the solution for it, if I am able to lazily initiaze it in fuse, I hope it could solve my problem. I am not able to figure out exact problem. How could i move ahead.

Thank you